# Appending data while doing Exchange partition in Oracle

Tags: oracle, archive

I am trying to build Archival method for my database application. I have few reporting tables which are already partitioned. These reporting tables are huge and are partitioned on monthly basis. I am using Exchange partition method for faster performance. By default the archival job runs every 30 days.

Note: I have specific archival tables for each reporting table.

Problem statement: I need to store archive data for an year in the archival tables. Can I append the data in archival tables using Exchange partitioning method?

Comment: Yes, that's the main purpose of exchange partition. However, I don't understand what you mean by "These reporting tables are huge and are partitioned on monthly basis. For this purpose I am using Exchange partition method for faster performance." What are you doing there?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit.. Sorry for creating confusion. I have edited that statement. I am just using Exchange partitioning to achieve my result. However, I am still not clear with your comment. Whether we can append data by some means in archive tables using Exchange partitioning or not?

Comment: From your problem statement, it seems that the archival table is NOT partitioned. If so, partition it and do the exchange partition again (using an intermediate table: alter table rep exchange partition ... with table C..., alter table archive_rep exchange partition ... with table C ....)

Comment: @gsalem.. a quick question.. I see your approach works while using "without validation" in the alter statement.. can I run do it without using this validation? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Doing exchange WITHOUT validation is a sure recipe for errors down the road. It will give you wrong results for queries. Don't do that. Just insure that the partitioning is the same between the 2 tables.

Comment: @gsalem... and how can I ensure the partitions are same between two tables? Since my main table is interval partitioned. Any code piece that can help me to understand this? Appreciate your help again.

Comment: Vaibhav, just insure that you have the same partitioning spec. As you use interval partitioning, insure that you have the same spec in both tables (e.g. interval (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH')). This makes it a bit more complex, as the paertition with which you need to exchange does not exist. So you need to do an insert into archive_table select * from original_table partition (..name_of_partition_to_exchange...) where rownum=1; rollback; and then exchange.